# How to Update Set with math in MySQL with CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I want to update data stock by adding the current data with the inputted data. What is the correct way?

```
public function addStock($tabel,$total,$id_barang){
    $this->db->set("total","total + $total");
    $this->db->where('id_barang',$id_barang);
    $this->db->update($tabel);  
}
```

The output should be the result of the addition, but it keeps returning 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append a `FALSE` third parameter on the `set()` method to prevent the query from being escaped :

```php
public function addStock($tabel,$total,$id_barang){
    $this->db->set("total","total + $total", false);
    $this->db->where('id_barang',$id_barang);
    $this->db->update($tabel);  
}
```